# Find entity with the biggest difference in a given column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I hava table profiles and I want to get the account with the most gained followers. I am using Postgresql. Note current record and previous record are all on the same table but with different timestamps.

```
id                                  |username       |person    |tweets|followers|following|likes|created_at|
------------------------------------|---------------|----------|------|---------|---------|-----|----------|
3fa34100-d688-4051-a687-ec49d05e7212|renok          |NULL      |   110|        6|        0|    0|2020-10-10|
bab9ceb9-2770-49ea-8489-77e5d763a223|Lydia_C        |test user2|   515|     1301|     1852| 1677|2020-10-10|
4649077a-9188-4821-a1ec-3b38608ea44a|Kingston_Sav   |NULL      |  2730|     1087|     1082| 1339|2020-10-10|
eef80836-e140-4adc-9598-8b612ab1825b|TP_s           |NULL      |  1835|      998|      956| 1832|2020-10-10|
fd3ff8c7-0994-40b6-abe0-915368ab9ae5|DKSnr4         |NULL      |   580|      268|      705|  703|2020-10-10|
3fa34100-d688-4051-a687-ec49d05e7212|renok          |NULL      |   119|        6|        0|    0|2020-10-12|
bab9ceb9-2770-49ea-8489-77e5d763a223|Lydia_C        |test user2|   516|     1301|     1852| 1687|2020-10-12|
4649077a-9188-4821-a1ec-3b38608ea44a|Kingston_Sav   |NULL      |  2737|     1090|     1084| 1342|2020-10-12|
eef80836-e140-4adc-9598-8b612ab1825b|TP_s           |NULL      |  1833|      998|      957| 1837|2020-10-12|
fd3ff8c7-0994-40b6-abe0-915368ab9ae5|DKSnr4         |NULL      |   570|      268|      700|  703|2020-10-12|
```

I have the logic in my mind but honestly I don't know how to express/think of it in terms of a sql query. This is my expected output.

```
id                                   | person | username      |gain      | 
-------------------------------------|--------|---------------|----------|
3fa34100-d688-4051-a687-ec49d05e7212 | NULL   | Kingston_Sav  | 3        |
```

The gain is will be the difference.

Any assistance is highly appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the expected output.

Comment: There's not quite enough context here for an answer.  How are you getting your current and previous resultsets?  Are they separate tables?

Comment: Am retrieving them like this `select * from profile where created_at=current_date` and `select * from profiles where created_at=currents_date - interval '1 day'` respectively.

Comment: Can you be sure all users have entries on each day?  What about weekends, etc.?

Comment: No some don't have.I which case created_at will be null for that day.

Comment: It is rare for there to be no entry on any particular day..So am not really concerned with that because there are checks on the code to take of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below answer worked for me.

```
 WITH cte AS (
       SELECT *, dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS rnk
       FROM   t
       )
    SELECT d1.*
         , d2.followers AS prev_followers
         , d1.followers - d2.followers AS gain
    FROM  (SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rnk = 1) d1
    JOIN  (SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rnk = 2) d2 USING (username)
    ORDER  BY gain DESC
    FETCH  FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES;
```

For more details and explanations check out this [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/278876/217646)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the most recent value for each using `distinct on` and the difference using `lag()`:

```
select distinct on (id) t.*
from (select t.*, 
             lag(followers) over (partition by id order by created_at) as prev_followers
      from t
     ) t
order by id, created_at desc;
```

You can then get the maximum with another ordering:

```
select t.*, (followers - prev_followers) as gain
from (select distinct on (id) t.*
      from (select t.*, 
                   lag(followers) over (partition by id order by created_at) as prev_followers
            from t
           ) t
      order by id, created_at desc
     ) t
order by (followers - prev_followers) desc
limit 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e111d08a0a9d97f9189ad3c56a84ee86) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I tried this approach combined both queries with an alias..but it aint working. I don't think It is doing what i ntend to do. I intend to get the difference between today's record and yesterday's record for each username e.g. i would like to know who gained the most followers by comparing the number of followers he/she had previously to what he/she has now then comparing this difference with other differences of other accounts.

Comment: @basebandit . . . I added `gains` to the `select`.  It appears to be doing what you want.